# If $u$ is divergence-free, then $u\cdot\nabla u$ doesn't need to be divergence-free too. Can we fix that?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, fluid-dynamics, divergence-operator

Let

- $d\in\mathbb N$
- $\Lambda$ be open
- $\mathcal V:=\left\{\phi\in C_c^\infty(\Lambda,\mathbb R^d):\nabla\cdot\phi=0\right\}$, $$V:=\overline{\mathcal V}^{\left\|\;\cdot\;\right\|_{H^1(\Lambda,\:\mathbb R^d)}}$$ and $$H:=\overline{\mathcal V}^{\left\|\;\cdot\;\right\|_{L^2(\Lambda,\:\mathbb R^d)}}$$
- $\operatorname P_H$ denote the orthogonal projection from $L^2(\Lambda,\mathbb R^d)$ onto $H$

Note that

1. $H$ is a closed subspace of $L^2(\Lambda,\mathbb R^d)$
2. $V$ is a closed subspace of $H_0^1(\Lambda,\mathbb R^d)$
3. $V=H\cap H_0^1(\Lambda,\mathbb R^d)$

If we assume that $\Lambda$ is bounded and $\partial\Lambda$ is Lipschitz, then $$V=\left\{u\in H_0^1(\Lambda,\mathbb R^d):\nabla\cdot u=0\right\}\;.\tag 1$$ Moreover, if $d\le 4$, then $$u\cdot\nabla v\in L^2(\Lambda,\mathbb R^d)\;\;\;\text{for all }u\in H_0^1(\Lambda,\mathbb R^d)\text{ and }v\in H_0^2(\Lambda,\mathbb R^d)\;.\tag 2$$

> **Question:**$\;\;\;$Let $u\in V\cap H^2(\Lambda,\mathbb R^d)$. I want to show that $$\text P_H(u\cdot\nabla u)\in V\;.\tag 3$$ Is that possible?

It's clear that $u\cdot\nabla u$ doesn't need to belong to $V$ and hence $\text P_H(u\cdot\nabla u)$ doesn't need to equal $u\cdot\nabla u$.

> However, if I'm not terribly wrong, the conclusion should be trivial: We know that $u\cdot\nabla u\in H_0^1(\Lambda,\mathbb R^d)$ and we should be able to conclude (this is the only part where I'm not sure) $\text P_H(u\cdot\nabla u)\in H_0^1(\Lambda,\mathbb R^d)$. The conclusion would now follow by (3.).

Comment: If $u$ is divergence free, doesn't that mean $\nabla u=0$?

Comment: @Arthur No, it does mean that $\nabla\cdot u=0$.

Comment: So what do you mean by $\nabla u$?

Comment: @Arthur As usual, $\nabla u$ denotes the gradient of $u$, i.e. $$\nabla:=\left(\frac\partial{\partial x_1},\ldots,\frac\partial{\partial x_d}\right)^T\;.$$ And, of course, in the context of $\nabla u$ this operator is applied componentwise to $u$.

Comment: What is the gradient of a vector field? The Jacobi matrix? Or is $u$ a scalar field? In that case, what does "divergence free" mean?

Comment: @Arthur $u\cdot\nabla u$ is a vector field. Its $i$th component is $(u\cdot\nabla u)_i=u\cdot\nabla u_i$.

Comment: I'm just confused, because you say that $u$ is divergence free, which is usually a property of vector fields, but then you say that $u$ has a gradient, which is a property of scalar fields. What is $u$?

Comment: @Arthur $u$ is a vector field. When I write $u\cdot\nabla u$, I mean the vector field whose $i$th component $(u\cdot\nabla u)_i$ is $u\cdot\nabla u_i$ (and $u_i$ denotes the $i$th component of $u$, which is a scalar field and hence has a gradient).