# If $\operatorname P_U$ denotes the orthogonal projection from $L^2$ onto a closed subspace $U$, can we conclude that $\text P_UH_0^1\subseteq H_0^1$

Tags: sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

Let

- $d\in\mathbb N$
- $\Lambda\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be open
- $U$ be a closed subspace of $L^2(\Lambda,\mathbb R^d)$
- $\operatorname P_U$ denote the orthogonal projection from $L^2(\Lambda,\mathbb R^d)$ onto $U$

> Can we show that $\text P_Uu\in H_0^1(\Lambda,\mathbb R^d)$ for all $u\in H_0^1(\Lambda,\mathbb R^d)$?

Comment: Pick any nonzero  $u \in L^2 \setminus H_0^1$ and let $U = \operatorname{sp} \{ u \}$. The latter space is closed since finite dimensional and since $P_Uu = u$, we have a counterexample.

Comment: @copper.hat Maybe you've misunderstood the question (by your choice, $u$ is not in $H_0^1(\Lambda,\mathbb R^d)$). I've made an edit and hope it's clearer now.

Comment: I like your login. Reminds me of debugging hardware over three decades ago.

Comment: @copper.hat As a side note: I've asked the question, cause I think it should be true for any choice of $\operatorname P_U$. However, if I'm wrong, please take in mind that I'm primarily interested in $\operatorname P_H$ from [my other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2053102/if-u-is-divergence-free-then-u-cdot-nabla-u-doesnt-need-to-be-divergence-f).

Comment: If there is some element $u \in L^2 \setminus H_0^1$, then the projection onto the line through $u$ will always be in $L^2 \setminus H_0^1$ (except for the origin, of course). So, if there is some $v \in H_0^1$ that is not orthogonal to $u$, then that would be a counterexample.

Comment: @copper.hat What about the $\operatorname P_H$ from [my other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2053102/if-u-is-divergence-free-then-u-cdot-nabla-u-doesnt-need-to-be-divergence-f)?

Answer (score 0):

Take $\Lambda = (0,1)$, $U = \{f \in L^2(\Lambda) \mid f(x) = 0 \text{ for a.e. } x \in (1/3,2/3)\}$, and $u(x) = x\,(1-x)$.

Comment: What about the $\operatorname P_H$ from [my other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2053102/if-u-is-divergence-free-then-u-cdot-nabla-u-doesnt-need-to-be-divergence-f)? Is the statementtrue in that case?

Comment: If I would know that answer, I would gave it.